# PHP and MySQLi UTF8

Tags: php, utf-8, mysqli

I have some tables that are set to `utf8_general_ci` and am using PHP's mysqli driver, with charset set to '`utf8`'.  I have the default_charset also set to `UTF-8`

However, characters are being replaced with '`\u0101l`'

Any idea what this is or how to fix it? Before I didn't have mysqli using utf8 and it just showed a question mark, not a diamond question mark - just a regular '?'

Thank you!

Comment: What about your PHP file coding? Is it UTF-8 too?

Comment: AFAIK MySQL won't ever JSON encode your characters. Please debug step by step at which point exactly this is happening.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you are using "htmlentities()"  or "html_entity_decode()" somewhere.  The issue is, htmlentities() is still trying to interpret its input to ISO-8859-1, while html_entity_decode() is now defaulting to UTF-8. Solution: If you are using any of these functions listed above, explicitly specify the encoding type every time. I had this problem  and a co-worker of mine wrote an article on the subject also http://lab.clearpixel.com.au/2012/01/html-entity-character-conversion-in-php/

I hope it helps